# Make translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints false when I added constraints

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, swift4

I make view programmatically and and when I want to add auto Layout to the view it’s painful to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` false every single time. Now I’m looking for any solution to make life easier.
Is there any extension or class that make it disable every time I want to add constraints?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you could add that line `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` in your view subclass. For instance, you usually use `UITextField`, or say `UIView`, for sure you have such base classes, like so:

```
import UIKit

/// Another Customized/Subclassed UIButton.
class BaseButton: UIButton {

    /// override init
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

            self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       }
    }

    /// override coder
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Or better yet, may I suggest, this one below? I use SnapKit for all my production level projects.

https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `UIView` class for constraints so that it applies to all the `UIControls` and custom `UIViews`.

```
extension UIView {
    func anchor(_ anotherView: UIView) {
        anotherView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addSubview(anotherView)
        anotherView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        anotherView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        anotherView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        anotherView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Example:

```
func setupView() {
    self.view.anchor(self.someImageView)
}
```